# Cannot get image and other mega for facebook open graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph, virtuemart

Please check the link:

http://kotinos.com.gr/index.php/en/2016-09-20-12-44-31/rings/ring-012498-detail

and if someone can tell me why on earth i get debug errors for not having type or image as meta, i will be grateful.

The issue is that i don't get Title, description or image at all and as you can see from page source i have it all (they are produced through php and added as meta values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug errors from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fkotinos.com.gr%2Findex.php%2Fen%2F2016-09-20-12-44-31%2Frings%2Fring-012498-detail is based on the URL before 303 HTTP Redirect, and the page source you view is from the URL after 303 HTTP Redirect.